# Subspaces of the space of all $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The exercise is to describe all the subspaces of $D$, the space of all $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices.

I just would have said $I$ and $Z$ initially, since you can't do much more to simplify a diagonal matrix.

The answer given is:

> The subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$ are $\mathbb{R}^4$ itself, three-dimensional planes $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$, two-dimensional subspaces ($\mathbf{n}_1\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$ and $\mathbf{n}_1\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$), one-dimensional lines through $(0,0,0,0)$, and $(0,0,0,0)$ by itself.

I cannot understand how $D$ is $\mathbb{R}^4$, much less understand the rest of the answer.

I can see how we might take the columns of $D$ and form linear combinations from them, but those column vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I suspect you have got the wrong answer. $D$ is a vector space of dimension 2.

Comment: $D$ is not $\mathbb{R}^4$. $D$ is only $\mathbb{R}^2$ (using the isomorphism that Hagen has shown in his answer, or as you have already noticed: the linear combination of columns of $D$ would be in $\mathbb{R}^2$). Therefore, the answer for part (b) of your link is inconsistent with your problem.

Comment: This isn't the first time I've encountered inconsistencies with Intro to Linear Algebra by Strang. It's actually a good book/course, but it needs more proof-reading.

Answer (score 1):

When we view the set of $2\times 2$ matrices as a (vector) space, we have to make clear *how* we do that, i.e., what it measn to add two elements of this space and what it means to multiply an element of this space by a real number. The somewhat obvious choices for these operations are
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a+a'&b+b'\\c+c'&d+d'\end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$\lambda \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}\lambda a&\lambda b\\\lambda c&\lambda d\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then one notices that the map $$(a,b,c,d)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} $$
is (again, somewhat obviously) an isomorphism of $\mathbb R^4$ with the space f $2\times 2$ matrices. Therefore the classification of subspaces of the space of $2\times 2$ matrices is "the same" as the classification of subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$.

For this task it does not matter that $2\times 2$ matrices have an additional structure beyond that as a vector space (namely, that matrices can be multiplied).

Morover, the space of diagonal $2\times 2$ matrices is a subspace of the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices that is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. Again, an explicit isomorphism is straightforward to write down: $(x,y)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x&0\\0&y\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: But he is only looking at diagonal matrices.

Comment: At the time of this comment, this answer is somewhat poorly organized: you seem to be emphasizing $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ for most of it, and then $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is dropped in as a footnote towards the end, when in fact the question *only* concerns the diagonal matrices. The result is that this discussion of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, which *is* relevant in a broader context, might be confusing/unmotivated to the OP in this situation.

Comment: To quote the OP (or rather the answer he has found and does not understand) "The subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$ are ...", so I thought it adequate to explain where $\Bbb R^4$ pops up in the task of describing the diagonal matrices