# All subspaces of $2\times 2$diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know all subspaces of a $2\times 2$
diagonal matrix. This is a problem from a book, Introduction to Linear Algebra by Dr. Strang. In the problem, I would like to find all subspaces of a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix.

The answer says that

> "The subspaces of D are D itself, the zero matrix by itself, and all
> the “one-dimensional” subspaces that contain all multiples of one
> fixed matrix."

the fixed matrix is \begin{bmatrix} d1 & 0\\ 0 & d2 \end{bmatrix}

I understand that the subspaces contain D itself and the zero matrix. However, what does it mean that “one-dimensional” subspaces that contain all multiples of one
fixed matrix" ? The related question is posted in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450033/subspaces-of-the-space-of-all-2-times-2-diagonal-matrices), but I do not really understand it.

Comment: $\pmatrix{d_1&0\\0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\\0&d_2}$

Comment: You are misstating and misunderstanding the question. There is not a fixed matrix. We are looking at the set of *all* diagonal matrices. That is the vector space of which he's asking for subspaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subspace must have all the properties of a vector space. In particular, summing two elements must yield a new element in the same subspace, and multiplying an element by a scalar will also result in an element of the subspace. What does that mean for this problem? First we need to find out the dimensionality of $D$, which is $2$. So a subspace can have dimensionality $2$, $D$ itself, dimensionality $0$, the zero matrix, or dimensionality $1$. This implies that you have a basis of the subspace with exactly one element. What element is that? It can be any element of $D\ne 0$. Let's call this basis vector the matrix $M$, where
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$$ Then the set $S$ of all matrices of the form $\lambda M, \lambda\in\mathbb R$ is a subspace of $D$. You have from definition that $\lambda_1M\in S$. If $\lambda_1M,\lambda_2M\in S$, then $$\lambda_1M+\lambda_2M=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)M\in S$$
If $M=0$, then $\lambda M=0$, so the subspace has only one element.

Answer (score 1):

One dimensional subspaces that contain multiples of one fixed matrix are multiples of $\left(\begin{matrix}d1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&d2\end{matrix}\right), \text { or }\left(\begin{matrix}d1&0\\0&d2\end{matrix}\right), d1,d2\ne 0$. It is clear that the vector space $D$ has dimension 2. That is to say, each diagonal matrix in that vector space has 2 degrees of freedom. You can get from any diagonal matrix d to another diagonal matrix d' in at most two moves if you add/subtract a multiple of two arbitrarily chosen linearly independent diagonal matrices.

Now what happens when we restrict the subspace to be a multiple of one fixed matrix- Any matrix in the resulting subspace has only one degree of freedom because you can get to another matrix in the subspace by adding a multiple of a single matrix. Visually, perhaps the matrices all lie on one line. Any diagonal matrix from the original vector space had 2 degrees of freedom though, so this second degree of freedom is lost when you restrict to only a multiple of one fixed matrix.

Looking at the other post, you've got subspaces of dimension 2 (the entire D), dimension 1 (given n, the set of all d such that $\langle n, d\rangle_F=0$ (this reduces the degree of freedom on any element d in the sub space by 1 because it is no longer allowed to vary in the direction spanned by n)), and dimension 0 $\langle n_1, d\rangle_F=0 \&\langle n_2, d\rangle_F=0$, $n_1,n_2$ linearly independent (this reduces the degree of freedom of any element in the sub space by 2 because d is not allowed to vary in the directions of n_1 and n_2; but since there were only two degrees of freedom to begin with, the resulting dimension is 0).